# Problemas com seletores do Jquery

Tags: jquery, array, value, array-associativo, each

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho esse código:

```js
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#simular').each(function(){
          $(this).click(function(){
                    
                    $("input[name=proteina2],input[name=quantidade2]").each(function(){  
                        var proteina2 = Number($(this).val());
                        if (!isNaN(proteina2)) prot = proteina2; 
                        alert(prot);
                    });    
                     
         });
    });

});
</script>
```

Ele pega os valores dos campos nomeados de "proteina2" e "quantidade2" que fazem um loop no php mostrando valores...O que eu preciso não é muito difícil eu creio, mas como sou novo em Jquery, queria uma ajuda pra compreender melhor essa parte.
Eu queria pegar os valores do campo "proteina2" e "quantidade2" e somar de forma separada sendo que pegue todos os valores do loop para esses campos. Por exemplo, eu tenho lá:

```
 Proteina2 | quantidade 2

   5           10

   4           2
```

No caso o que eu preciso é pegar todo o loop de "proteina2" e somar com "quantidade2" e geraria o seguinte resultado:

```
resultado: 15 

resultado: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa assim acho q resolve:

```
   $("input[name=proteina2],input[name=quantidade2]").each(function(){ 
       var quantidade2,proteina2 = 0;
       if($(this).attr('name') == 'proteina2'){
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
             proteina2 += Number($(this).val());
          }
       }else{
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
             quantidade2 += Number($(this).val());
          }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele vai somar todas proteinas ou todas quantidades. Eu queria um jeito de ele somar a 1º proteina com a 1º quantidade, a 2º proteina com a 2º quantidade. e assim por diante.

Comment: Ai precisa da sua estrutura HTML para ver como vai fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o resultado que eu queria dessa forma:

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#simular').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){

                   var prot = 0;
                   var quant = 0;
                   var teste = 0;
                   var totalquanti = 0;
                   var a = [];
                   var b = [];

                $('input[name=proteina2]').each(function(){
                        var proteina = Number($(this).val());
                        if (!isNaN(proteina)) prot = proteina;
                        a.push(prot);
                });

                $('input[name=quantidade2]').each(function(){
                    var quantidade = Number($(this).val());
                    if (!isNaN(quantidade)) quant = quantidade;
                    b.push(quant);
                });

                for (i=0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++){

                    if (a[i] != 0){
                        totalquanti += b[i]; 
                        conta = (a[i] * b[i])/100;
                        teste += conta;
                        nova = teste/totalquanti;
                    }
                }
                var totalconta = nova*100;
                var consegui = totalconta.toFixed(2);
                var final = "%";
                var end = consegui + final;

                $("#opa").html(end);

      });
   });
 });
</script>
```